# REGEXMATCH with regex reference to cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm filtering numbers on a gSheet by keyword, as selected by viewers from a pre-determined dropdown list created through data validation.

There are multiple options viewers can select, including "All". Because "All" is not a filterable keyword in the data source, I am using FILTER(REGEXMATCH(IF(...))) to sort the data. The dropdown list lives in cell B1, so I'm referencing this within the REGEXMATCH when the IF statement is false.

**Issue**: RegEx matches to text, not numbers. When I reference the cell B1, the formula errors out because it's not a text value. But when I make it a text value, it finds no match (of course).

---

**Current**:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!$E:$E,
REGEXMATCH(Sheet1!$I:$I,IF(B1="All","organic|paid|other",B1))=true),0))
```

- Column E is summed based on the keyword selected
- Column I contains the keyword(s) to match
- Cell B1 has the dropdown list where users select their keyword

---

**What I've tried**:

- `VALUE(B1)` - Referencing it as a value, with the hope it would then read the text that is returned; it errored from bad input
- `TEXT(B1)` - Referencing it as text; it read "B1"
- `"""&B1&"""` - Triple quotes, with the idea that the quoted quotes will pass and encase the text returnd by B1; it read "&B1&" (d'oh)
- `\"B1\"` - Escaping the cell reference; my first time trying to escape in regex, so this may very well be the right answer with a bad implementation

Any other ideas to reference cell B1 from within a REGEXMATCH expression?

Answer (score 4):

The value contained in cell B1 is referenced from any formula simply as B1. For example, `regexmatch(A1, B1)`.

When using an array, `=filter(A1:A10, regexmatch(A1:A10, B1))` would work.

If the range (A1:A10 in my example) contains numbers that need to be converted to text, one way to do this is to concatenate them with empty string (this works well with arrays): `=filter(A1:A10, regexmatch(A1:A10 & "", B1))`

#### Remarks

- It's redundant to write `regexmatch(...)=true`, just write `regexmatch(...)`.
- Consider the possibility that errors are cause by other parts of the formula; remove extraneous parts to isolate the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I took out the redundancy. It turned out the problem was a mismatch in letter case; the keywords were sentence case, while the text being matched to was all lowercase. I forgot how strict regex can be.